# How to get the value of an array of selected keys from swift array of dictionaries and the complexity of it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, big-o, higher-order-functions

Lets say I have got the below response. Two things I would like to know from the below operation.

1.) How to improve/optimise the below code using higher order functions in swift.

2.) Also would like to know the current complexity of the code and the complexity of any optimized code you may suggest.

In the below response I would like to check the values of only certain keys as described in keysToBeChecked and for that particular key I need to do an operation. Once the operation is done I want to add a new key(key6) to the response as shown below. The following operation works fine for me and that is what I intend to do. I am looking for the above 2 things mentioned

```
var response = [["key1": 1, "key2": 0, "name": "John", "key3": 1, "key4": 1, "place": "Newyork", "key5": 0],
                ["key1": 0, "key2": 1, "name": "Mike", "key3": 1, "key4": 0, "place": "California", "key5": 1],
                ["key1": 1, "key2": 0, "name": "John", "key3": 0, "key4": 1, "place": "Boston", "key5": 1]]
```

```swift
let keysToBeChecked = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5"]

for var item in response{
var dict = [String: String]()
   for(key, value) in item{
       if keysToBeChecked.contains(key){
           dict[key] = "\(value)"
           if dict[key] == "1"{
               //perform required operations
               output
           }
       }
   }

   item["key6"] = output
   response.append(item)
}
print(response)//should print the below


My expected output is

response = [["key1": 1, "key2": 0, "name": "John", "key3": 1, "key4": 1, "place": "Newyork", "key5": 0, "key6": "output"],
   ["key1": 0, "key2": 1, "name": "Mike", "key3": 1, "key4": 0, "place": "California", "key5": 1, "key6": "output"],
   ["key1": 1, "key2": 0, "name": "John", "key3": 0, "key4": 1, "place": "Boston", "key5": 1, "key6": "output"]]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is all `key(1...6)` means? If you getting this values from real response, better to create model than conform to `Codable`

Comment: @vpoltave key(1...6) is nothing but 6 different keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **higher order function**, you can try,

```
let result = response.map { (dict) -> [String:Any] in
    var filteredDict = [String:Any]()
    dict.forEach({ (key, value) in
        if keysToBeChecked.contains(key) {
            filteredDict[key] = value
            if (value as? Int) == 1 {
                filteredDict["key6"] = "output"
            }
        }
    })
    return filteredDict
}
```

Comment: Thanks@PGDev. That worked partially. Also I need to check if element.key value equals to 1 and perform an operation to get desired output before adding key6.

Comment: Updated the answer as per your requirement.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Any insights regarding the complexity of your suggested approach and the one I posted?

Comment: Complexity would be numberOfDict * numberOfKeys.

Comment: Do accept (tick on left) if the answer helped. Happy coding..